# Join 3 tables with different FKs

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, inner-join, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to join 3 tables together in a SELECT query with some WHERE clauses.
Table 1 is linked to Table 2, and Table 2 is linked to Table 3.

The tables are as follows:

```
Author
PK: Author_ID
FK: Location_ID
Author_First_Name

Location
PK: Location_ID
City

Articles
PK: Article_ID
FK: Author_ID
Article_Name
```

So far I've put together this Query, but am having trouble determining how to to Join the second Foreign Key 'Location_ID'

```
SELECT 
    Articles.Article_Name 
FROM 
    Articles
        INNER JOIN Author
            ON Articles.Author_ID
        INNER JOIN Location
            ON 
WHERE Author.Author_First_Name='Sam'
AND Location.City<>'Detroit'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is something like this:

```
SELECT a.Article_Name
FROM Articles a INNER JOIN
     Author au 
     ON a.Author_ID = au.Author_ID INNER JOIN
     Location l
     ON l.Location_ID = au.Location_Id
WHERE au.First_Name = 'Sam' AND l.City <> 'Detroit';
```

Note the use of table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  Also, you need conditions connecting the two tables for the `ON` clauses.

Comment: Well, Location_ID is only referenced in a Foreign Key in the Author table.
Does this mean it must be joined to the Author table? If so, will the original select from the Article table still be valid?

Comment: @milesg . . . I saw that in your question but neglected to delete the comment.

Comment: Thank you, I think I've got it now. With one last question: is this good use of inner join, or would another join type be beneficial? My understanding is this way if there is no City, it will be filtered out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want an `INNER JOIN`, but your question does not have enough information to really decide.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to compare table fields

```
SELECT * FROM articles ar
LEFT JOIN author a ON ar.author_id = a.author_id
LEFT JOIN location l ON a.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE a.author_first_name = 'Sam' AND l.city <> 'Detroit'
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Using inner join, if you have a null location on a specific article, this query wouldn't return this article. With left join it gets all articles even those which location is null.

Comment: @Joao Punho is right. Use left join on articles will give you all article regardless of whether  author or location is available.